# Finding the vector equation of a plane from cartesian

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, plane-geometry

> Find the vector equation for a plane with cartesian equation $x-3y+2z=5$.

My work.
I have managed to use vector techniques to find the equation as follows:
$x=5+3y-2z$
$$(x,y,z)=(5+3y-2z, y, z)$$
Factoring out the $y$ and $z$,
$$(x,y,z)=(5,0,0)+y(3,1,0)+z(-2,0,1).$$
In terms of scalars:
$$(x,y,z)=(5,0,0)+s(3,1,0)+t(-2,0,1).$$ 
However, our lecturer emphasized on trying to use linear algebra, particularly Gauss reduction, to find the vector equation of planes from cartesian. I'm not too sure of how to go around this. Could someone please help me use linear algebra for this question? Thanks:)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your answer.  But if you want another way, it's not hard to find two noncollinear vectors perpendicular to $(1,-3,2)$ (one easy method is to make one component $0$ and then swap the other two, negating one of them: e.g. $(3,1,0)$) and then one point on the plane (just plug in $2$ arbitrary numbers (both $0$ being the easiest) and solve for the third).

Answer (score 1):

let us compute three points of this equation $$x-3y+2z=5$$ for example $$P_1(5,0,0),P_2(0,1,4),P_3(1,0,2)$$ then you can compute the equation of the plane as follows:
$$[x,y,z]=(5,0,0)+\alpha(-5,1,4)+\beta(-4,0,2)$$ with real numbers $$\alpha,\beta$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let $M$ be a point with coordinates $(x,y,z)$, $O$ the origin. Think of dot product.